# Convert text within a TextView into links that start an activity

Tags: android, textview, android-textattributes

I have a TextView which contains a (Possibly large) string that may contain one or more "links." These links aren't standard "www." links but rather they will need to launch a new activity. How do I take some large text, scan it for words beginning with "/r/" or "r/", and change those words to clickable elements that will launch an activity? I suspect I need to use [Linkify](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify#addLinks) but after looking at some examples, I am still unclear as to how to use it.

The following is an example of the text I need to convert to links (note the bolded text are the pieces that need to be converted to links):

> Some text that has **/r/some** links. This **r/text** might have many **/r/many** links.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ClickableSpan`. Here is an example of how to span a text:

```
    String text = "Some very nice text here. CLICKME. Don't click me.";
    String word = "CLICKME";
    // when user clicks that word it opens an activity

    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
    int position = text.indexOf(word); // find the position of word in text
    int length = word.length(); // length of the span, just for convenience

    ClickableSpan mySpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(mIntent);
        }
    };

    ssb.setSpan(mySpan, position, (position+length), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    // setSpan needs 4 things: a Span object, beginning of the span, end of span, and 
    // and a modifier, which for now you can just c&p

    TextView txtView = findViewById(R.id.txt);
    txtView.setClickable(true);
    txtView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    // dont delete this last line. Without it, clicks aren't registered

    txtView.setText(ssb);
```

You can set multiple spans on different places in text and they will all do what you tell them to do in `onClick()`